# kinect unity3d face tracking

Tags: unity-game-engine, kinect

i want to place a mask on a user's face tracking the head to match movement and rotation and at the end grab a 30 second video of the performer.
i've been looking how to use kniect face tracking example inside unity3d and i can't find any related information?
...i've check a kinect wrapper http://wiki.etc.cmu.edu/unity3d/index.php/Microsoft_Kinect_-_Microsoft_SDK but it works with skeletal not only the face, anyone  could point me to a solution on this?

Answer (score 1):

The official Microsoft Kinect for Windows Developer Toolkit v1.6 has examples of what you are trying to do:
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=34807

Looking at those should have a great deal of re-use if you are wanting to port it to a different platform.